# How can i get dynamic field from json request in JAX-WS (JAX_RS)

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs, rest

I have an api for which I am receiving a Java pojo request in json format:

```
{
   "migrationId" : "32n2342342j";
   "someDynamicField" : {"A" : "", 
                        "B" : ""}
}
```

This `someDynamicField` can have different property name for which I need to extra the data from.

I cannot have a class for this model since that field is dynamic. 
But for sure that `someDynamicField` will be of string type but name will be different.

One thing is for sure that `someDynamicField` can be one of the string from the finite set for eg: ["move", "source"....] and this set will grow in future.

For example :

```
{
   "migrationId" : "32n2342342j";
   "move" : {"sourHost" : "", 
             "targetHost" : ""}
}
```

sometime it can be

```
{
   "migrationId" : "32n2342342j";
   "delete" : {"sourHost" : "", 
             "targetHost" : ""}
}
```

What would be the best way to extract this information from the request?

I tried to look at this one : [How to map dynamic JSON in JAX-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429054/how-to-map-dynamic-json-in-jax-rs) 
 Here they use the vairable name explicitly  and in my case the field is dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a String instead of an Object and parse it with Jackson.  This isn't the complete code but something like:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/blah")
public Response myMethod(String inputObject) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(inputObject);

    String migrationId = jsonNode.get("migrationId");

    if( jsonNode.has("move") ) {
        handleMoveNode(jsonNode.get("move"));
    }
    else if( jsonNode.has("delete") ) {
        handleDeleteNode(jsonNode.get("delete"));
    }
    
    // handle the other node types

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

The point is to take a String in your JAX-RS method and parse it yourself.

Comment: I haven't tried it but I think the Jackson JAX-RS provider will support having the JsonNode as a parameter so you don't have to manually manage the ObjectMapper. I may be wrong though.